# Dual boot with Windows 10 and Fedora 25 stopped working: Grub is gone

Tags: fedora, windows, dual-boot

I had installed Windows 10 and Fedora 25 and worked fine for a while.

Suddenly, the grub is gone. I'm also not able to see the BIOS splash screen neither the nVidia splash screen. The monitor stays turned off until it starts with the Windows 10 loading screen.

I don't remember doing anything which could broke this. Maybe a Windows update?

Comment: Since Windows should not have access to disable the BIOS splash screen, the issue probably came from another level such as a BIOS update or settings that got changed.  You should check those first.  http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=303738 might be useful to fix your grub.

Comment: I am almost certain that this is Windows' [fast startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) (also known as quick boot mode) in action. **Is fast startup enabled in your Windows installation?**

Comment: Probably fast startup, hibernation or suspend to ram, has signalled the firmware bootloader (bios well not really but most people call it that) to boot differently.

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/667484/restore-efi-from-windows-after-windows-10-upgade-broke-boot-list

Answer (score 2):

Running this command as administrator works for me:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\fedora\grubx64.efi
```

hope that works you too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try boot-repair. This can be downloaded as an iso and made into a bootable usb drive or CD/DVD.

You can then boot from it and it will normally find your Linux partition and reinstate it to the grub menu.

You can download boot-repair from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

You could also boot from a live DVD/USB and install boot-repair from the download manager.

A third possibility would be to try Refind which works well for EFI booting systems.